# Get a given field from the most recent document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to get the _id field of the most recent document entered into the collection.

I have created a collection called Rooms:

```
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');
```

and this code should get the most recent item limited to one:

```
Rooms.find({}, {fields: {'_id':1}}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```

instead, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Rooms.find(...).sort is not a function(…)
```

Where am I going wrong?

**Solution (thanks @aedm**)

---

```
var roomID = Rooms.findOne({}, {fields: {_id: 1}, sort: {_id: -1}});
return roomID._id.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection.find` returns a cursor, not an array. Cursors don't have a `sort` method. Try the following instead:

```
Rooms.findOne({}, {fields: {_id: 1}, sort: {_id: -1}});
```

http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find

**Edit:**

As @MichelFloyd pointed out, `_id`'s generated by Meteor are **not** sorted chronologically like the ones created by MongoDB itself. In order to sort by creation date, you'll have to store those timestamps in your collection.

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to get it to return the raw text of the id, instead of an object like it returns now?

Comment: Use `myRoom._id.toString()`.

Comment: `myRoom._id` is already a string, no need to cast it. Also, `_id` is *not sorted by time* (unless you are managing `_id`s by yourself). The native Meteor `_id` is a random string.

Comment: I just ran a small test, and found that @MichelFloyd is quite right about that. _id's generated by MongoDB itself are chronologically sorted to the granularity of a second, but for some reason Meteor creates a random id instead even if you specify `{idGeneration: 'MONGO'}`. I don't quite understand why that is, but you better not trust the timestamp of Meteor's Mongo _id's. As for `_id` being a string, that's mostly true, but not true for collections with `{idGeneration: 'MONGO'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Would've commented, but don't have the rep yet. You can get the id as string with: Rooms.findOne({}, {fields: {_id: 1}, sort: {_id: -1}})._id;